# Youtube link src

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have problem with link to youtube. I get json "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kqEfk801E94" and How can I add to src ? I read but this link is incorrect because dont have a embed. Example https://www.youtube.com/embed/kqEfk801E94, don't
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kqEfk801E94. How can I do it and replace iframe src?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question exactly, but I think you want to know what kind of YouTube URL to use in an iframe.  If so, the embed works.

If you are writing your own HTML, you can use the embed link in an iframe src directly.  This small HTML page loads the URL you linked to:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-gb">
  <head>
    <title>YouTube Embed</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/kqEfk801E94" />
  </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**: I see you tagged this as Vue.js and JavaScript.  If you have an asynchronous response with the embed URL, if you set a local data value, computed property or prop, Vue.js will automatically bind the variable and set it, so you'd only have to do something like:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <iframe :src="url" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        url: ''
      }
    },
    methods: {
      async loadYouTubeUrl() {
        const response = await fetch('api/videos/:id/get') // wherever your API is
        const json = await response.json()
        this.url = json.url // wherever this property is
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what tools you have available to you to put links into HTML documents from JSON, or the structure of what you're using, but if you can write JavaScript, you can modify the URL link with a regular expression to convert it from a watch to an embed URL, then you can use `document.querySelector` to find your `iframe` and then update the `src` attribute.

This all assumes you have a function that operates after your JSON call.  Since I don't know your mechanisms for the JSON, I'll assume you already have the JSON string in a variable called `json`.  Here's an example script:

```
function getEmbedUrlFrom(json) {
  const data = JSON.parse(json)
  const url = data.url
  const embedUrl = url.replace(/watch\?v=/, 'embed/')
  return embedUrl
}

function updateIframeUrl(url) {
  const iframe = document.querySelector('iframe')
  iframe.src = url
}

updateIframeUrl(getEmbedUrlFrom(json))
```